# NodeJs application experiencing frequent downtime

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I've a node js application on 16GB machine and is hosted on PM2. The node version is 16.20 and npm version is 9.8. I've set the --max-old-space-size=13000 in both ecosystem.config.js as well as in advanced system settings. Still I see frequent application downtime. I need help in resolving this issue as the application is being used by the clients and they're at the verge of escalating this to the higher management. Below is the heap log I've captured and the error that is recorded when the application is down.

**Heap log**:
"RSS: 417026048 Heap Total: 355098624 Heap Used: 294669464"

**Error log**:

```
> <--- Last few GCs --->
> 
> [3428:0000015046ABE0B0]     6312 ms: Scavenge 67.3 (88.6) -> 60.3
> (90.7) MB, 23.2 / 0.2 ms  (average mu = 0.978, current mu = 0.978)
> allocation failure  [3428:0000015046ABE0B0]     6705 ms: Scavenge 72.1
> (91.3) -> 63.7 (96.3) MB, 29.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.978, current
> mu = 0.978) allocation failure  [3428:0000015046ABE0B0]     6962 ms:
> Scavenge 76.7 (96.7) -> 65.1 (97.8) MB, 20.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu =
> 0.978, current mu = 0.978) allocation failure 
> 
> 
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
> 
> FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
> out of memory  1: 00007FF6FB4B15AF   2: 00007FF6FB3CC5EF   3:
> 00007FF6FC0AEF82   4: 00007FF6FBD5D5DE   5: 00007FF6FB8F7DC7   6:
> 00007FF6FC1DB734   7: 00007FF6FC1DDD4B   8: 00007FF6FC1DDA81   9:
> 00007FF6FC1DC3EB  10: 00007FF6FC1DC131  11: 00007FF6FC184E17  12:
> 00007FF6FC163BFC  13: 00007FF6FC184960  14: 00007FF6FC1850C6  15:
> 00007FF6FC184EB2  16: 00007FF6FC165C7D  17: 00007FF6FC156374  18:
> 00007FF6FC1626B7  19: 00007FF6FC15DFB1  20: 00007FF6FBCF4FE1  21:
> 00007FF6FBCC6149  22: 00007FF6FBCC6C1A  23: 00007FF6FB3CEF7D  24:
> 00007FF6FB4FF30D  25: 00007FF6FC319250  26: 00007FF91A5D7AC4  27:
> 00007FF91CB8A351 RtlUserThreadStart+33
> 
> 
> #
> # Fatal error in , line 0
> # Fatal process out of memory: Zone
> #
> #
> #
> #FailureMessage Object: 00000037EEBFA0D0
```

Comment: i will be happy to help but you have to share some code .
a server should be statless and shuldnt consume this amount of RAM
its probably a memory leak

Comment: Hi Naor, thank you for responding. Actually, I'm not sure where exactly the problem is in the code or where is the memory leak. Do you want me to share the app.js code?

Comment: yes, if its confidutial you can share 2 snapshot of heapdump module

Comment: Actually there is no heapdump module Naor and I'm facing issues installing it.

Comment: ok so you need to supply code

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the application attempts to use more memory than it is allocated with.

This is what I would do:

1. Look for the places where the memory can be consumed more. Examples: large files processings(image, video, spreadsheets, etc.)
2. Look for allocating memory in a loop(ex: reading content of files in a loop & storing them in an array)
3. Look for network connections are dropped properly & ensure that there are no references after them
4. Look for places that updates local-global values. Ex: Updating a global or file global array in each incoming request
5. If the occurrences of #4 & #5 is found, it is a easy fix.
6. For #1 & #2, I would figure out a stream lined way to process the large files, like create queue and offload the processing to an another process etc.
7. If the memory usage is simply due to processing & no memory leak is detected(yes, the first 4 points indicates memory leak), I would gather what is the peak memory usage & set that to the node.js process(There is a parameter in Node.js that changes the available memory to a Node.js process.)